# Google Maps API 3 pan to new bounds after applying a jquery filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I need to zoom and reset the bounds on a google map after applying a filter. The initial map is plotted and the bounds are set. When I apply a filter by location, the farm filter, I need it to reset the bounds and pan to that location or the new set of bounds as determined by the filtered markers.

I found an example of the basic filters to work off here [github marker filtering with google maps](https://github.com/Twilliamson90/Marker-Filtering-Google-Maps). I adapted it to fit my needs. The json comes from a mysql db with php.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grantiago/3v16zsfh/) without a working function to pan to the new bounds.

The json:

```
var personData = [{
"id": "18",
"firstname": "Jim",
"type": "Grape",
"farm": "Sweet",
"lat": "44.231953",
"lng": "-116.908485",
"date_s": "2016",
"month": "12"
}, 
{
"id": "1",
"firstname": "Grant",
"type": "Grape",
"farm": "Kerner",
"lat": "44.232029",
"lng": "-116.891426",
"date_s": "2016",
"month": "11"
}, 
{
"id": "2",
"firstname": "Grant",
"type": "Apple",
"farm": "Kerner",
"lat": "44.252029",
"lng": "-116.811426",
"date_s": "2017",
"month": "11"
},
{
"id": "29",
"firstname": "Grant",
"type": "Corn",
"farm": "Two Rivers",
"lat": "44.229061",
"lng": "-116.970703",
"date_s": "2018",
"month": "11"
}]
```

The google map js:

```
var myMap = function() {
var options = {
disableDefaultUI: true,
//zoom: 16,
//center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.237226, -116.912341),
//center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
}
function init(settings) 
{map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(settings.idSelector), options);
markerLocation = settings.markerLocation;
loadMarkers();}
var bounds = new 
google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
var iconBase = 'https://lrio.com/kml/icons/';
var icons = {
Hen: {
  icon: iconBase + 'hen.png'
},
Rooster: {
  icon: iconBase + 'rooster.png'
},
 Grape: {
  icon: iconBase + 'grape.png'
},
 Corn: {
  icon: iconBase + 'corn.png'
},
 Apple: {
  icon: iconBase + 'apple.png'
},
Quail: {
  icon: iconBase + 'quail.png'
}
};

markers = {};
markerList = [];
function loadMarkers(personList) {
// optional argument of person
var people = (typeof personList !== 'undefined') ? personList : personData;

var j = 1; // for lorempixel
// called people not location
for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
var person = people[i];
if (markerList.indexOf(person.id) !== -1) continue;

  var lat = person.lat,
    lng = person.lng,
    markerId = person.id;

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 400
  });
  // set the custom icon marker
  var icon = iconBase[person.type] || {};
  //var icon = customIcons[person.type] || {};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
// here
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
title: person.firstname,
markerId: markerId,
icon: icons[person.type].icon,
map: map});
//fit bounds step 2 of 3
bounds.extend(marker.position);
//var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
markers[markerId] = marker;
markerList.push(person.id);


var content = ['<div class="iw-text"><strong>', person.firstname,
    '</strong><br>Type: ', person.type, '<br>Date: ', person.date_s,
    '<br>Farm: ', person.farm, '<br>ID: ', person.id, '<br><img src="', icons[person.type].icon, '"></div></div>'
  ].join('');


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
    return function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(content);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, content));

}

/* =====
 fit bounds step 3 of 3
 ======= */

map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.panToBounds(bounds);
}
```

the filters:

```
function removePersonMarker(id) {
if (markers[id]) {
markers[id].setMap(null);
loc = markerList.indexOf(id);
if (loc > -1) markerList.splice(loc, 1);
delete markers[id];
}
}

/*
    ======
    FILTER
    ======
*/

// default all filters off
var filter = {
type: 0,
firstname: 0,
date_s: 0,
month: 0,
date: 0,
farm: 0
}
var filterMap;

/*
    Helper function
    @param array a (array of arrays)
    @return array (common elements from all arrays)
*/
function reduceArray(a) {
r = a.shift().reduce(function(res, v) {
if (res.indexOf(v) === -1 && a.every(function(a) {
    return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
})) res.push(v);
return res;
}, []);
return r;
}

/*
    Helper function
    @param string n
    @return bool
*/
function isInt(n) {
return n % 1 === 0;
}


/*
    Decides which filter function to call and stacks all filters together
    @param string filterType (the property that will be filtered upon)
    @param string value (selected filter value)
    @return undefined
*/
function filterCtrl(filterType, value) {
// result array
var results = [];

if (isInt(value)) {
filter[filterType] = parseInt(value);
} else {
filter[filterType] = value;
}

for (k in filter) {
if (!filter.hasOwnProperty(k) && !(filter[k] !== 0)) {
// all the filters are off
loadMarkers();
return false;
} else if (filter[k] !== 0) {
// call filterMap function and append to r array
results.push(filterMap[k](filter[k]));
} else {
// fail silently
}
}

if (filter[filterType] === 0) results.push(personData);

/*
    if there is 1 array (1 filter applied) set it,
    else find markers that are common to every results array (pass every filter)
*/
if (results.length === 1) {
results = results[0];
} else {
results = reduceArray(results);
}

loadMarkers(results);

}

/* 
    The keys in this need to be mapped 1-to-1 with the keys in the filter variable.
*/
filterMap = {
/*date: function( value ) {
    return filterIntsLessThan('date_s', value);
},
*/
year: function(value) {
return filterByString('date_s', value);
},
month: function(value) {
return filterByString('month', value);
},
name: function(value) {
return filterByString('firstname', value);
},
farm: function(value) {
return filterByString('farm', value);
},
type: function(value) {
return filterByString('type', value);
}
}

/*
    Filters marker data based upon a string match
    @param string dataProperty (the key that will be filtered upon)
    @param string value (selected filter value)
    @return array (people that made it through the filter)
*/
function filterByString(dataProperty, value) {
var people = [];

for (var i = 0; i < personData.length; i++) {
var person = personData[i];
if (person[dataProperty] == value) {
people.push(person);
} else {
removePersonMarker(person.id);
}
}
return people;
}

/*
    Filters out integers that are under the provided value
    @param string dataProperty (the key that will be filtered upon)
    @param int value (selected filter value)
    @return array (people that made it through the filter)
*/
function filterIntsLessThan(dataProperty, value) {
var people = [];

for (var i = 0; i < personData.length; i++) {
var person = personData[i];
if (person[dataProperty] > value) {
people.push(person)
} else {
removePersonMarker(person.id);
}
}
return people;
}

// Takes all the filters off
function resetFilter() {
filter = {
//followers: 0,
//college: 0,
//from: 0, 
type: 0,
firstname: 0,
date_s: 0,
month: 0,
date: 0,
farm: 0
}
}

return {
init: init,
loadMarkers: loadMarkers,
filterCtrl: filterCtrl,
resetFilter: resetFilter
};
}();


$(function() {

var mapConfig = {
idSelector: 'map-canvas',

// nope
//  map.fitBounds(bounds);
//  map.panToBounds(bounds);
}

myMap.init(mapConfig);

$('.load-btn').on('click', function() {
var $this = $(this);
// reset everything
$('select').val(0);
myMap.resetFilter();
myMap.loadMarkers();


if ($this.hasClass('is-success')) {
$this.removeClass('is-success').addClass('is-default');
}
});


$('.name-select').on('change', function() {
myMap.filterCtrl('name', this.value);
});

$('.farm-select').on('change', function() {
myMap.filterCtrl('farm', this.value);
// nope
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
myMap.panTo(bounds);
});

$('.type-select').on('change', function() {
myMap.filterCtrl('type', this.value);
});

$('.year-select').on('change', function() {
myMap.filterCtrl('year', this.value);
});
$('.month-select').on('change', function() 
{
myMap.filterCtrl('month', this.value);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `loadMarkers` function, create a new `bounds` object every time and move the code that computes the bounds to always execute:

```
function loadMarkers(personList) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  //  <snip>

  for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var person = people[i];
    var lat = person.lat,
      lng = person.lng,
      markerId = person.id;
    var posn = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    //fit bounds step 2 of 3
    bounds.extend(posn);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cmuvgkz0/)

[image: screenshot of map after selecting grape]

**code snippet:**

```js
var myMap = function() {

  var options = {
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    //zoom: 16,
    //center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.237226, -116.912341),
    //center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }

  /*
   Load the map then markers
   @param object settings (configuration options for map)
   @return undefined
  */
  function init(settings) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(settings.idSelector), options);
    markerLocation = settings.markerLocation;
    loadMarkers();
  }
  // fit bounds 1 of 1
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  /*
   =======
   MARKERS
   =======
  */

  // using this one from developers example
  var iconBase = 'https://lrio.com/kml/icons/';
  var icons = {
    Hen: {
      icon: iconBase + 'hen.png'
    },
    Miss: {
      icon: iconBase + 'shell.png'
    },
    Rooster: {
      icon: iconBase + 'rooster.png'
    },
    Grape: {
      icon: iconBase + 'grape.png'
    },
    Corn: {
      icon: iconBase + 'corn.png'
    },
    Apple: {
      icon: iconBase + 'apple.png'
    },
    Quail: {
      icon: iconBase + 'quail.png'
    }
  };

  markers = {};
  markerList = [];

  /*
   Load markers onto the Google Map from a provided array or demo personData (data.js)
   @param array personList [optional] (list of people to load)
   @return undefined
  */
  function loadMarkers(personList) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // optional argument of person
    var people = (typeof personList !== 'undefined') ? personList : personData;

    var j = 1; // for lorempixel
    // called people not location
    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      var person = people[i];
      var lat = person.lat,
        lng = person.lng,
        markerId = person.id;
      var posn = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      //fit bounds step 2 of 3
      bounds.extend(posn);
      // if its already on the map, dont put it there again
      if (markerList.indexOf(person.id) !== -1)
        continue;

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        maxWidth: 400
      });
      // set the custom icon marker
      var icon = iconBase[person.type] || {};
      //var icon = customIcons[person.type] || {};

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // here
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: person.firstname,
        markerId: markerId,
        icon: icons[person.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
      //fit bounds step 2 of 3
      bounds.extend(marker.position);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      map.panToBounds(bounds);
      //var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      markers[markerId] = marker;
      markerList.push(person.id);


      var content = ['<div class="iw-text"><strong>', person.firstname,
        '</strong><br>Type: ', person.type, '<br>Date: ', person.date_s,
        '<br>Farm: ', person.farm, '<br>ID: ', person.id, '<br><img src="', icons[person.type].icon, '"></div></div>'
      ].join('');


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
        return function() {
          infoWindow.setContent(content);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, content));
    }

    /* =====
     fit bounds step 3 of 3
     ======= */
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.panToBounds(bounds)
  }

  /*
   Remove marker from map and our list of current markers
   @param int id (id of the marker element)
   @return undefined
  */
  function removePersonMarker(id) {
    if (markers[id]) {
      markers[id].setMap(null);
      loc = markerList.indexOf(id);
      if (loc > -1) markerList.splice(loc, 1);
      delete markers[id];
    }
  }

  /*
   ======
   FILTER
   ======
  */

  // default all filters off
  var filter = {
    type: 0,
    firstname: 0,
    date_s: 0,
    month: 0,
    date: 0,
    farm: 0
  }
  var filterMap;

  /*
   Helper function
   @param array a (array of arrays)
   @return array (common elements from all arrays)
  */
  function reduceArray(a) {
    r = a.shift().reduce(function(res, v) {
      if (res.indexOf(v) === -1 && a.every(function(a) {
          return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
        })) res.push(v);
      return res;
    }, []);
    return r;
  }

  /*
   Helper function
   @param string n
   @return bool
  */
  function isInt(n) {
    return n % 1 === 0;
  }


  /*
   Decides which filter function to call and stacks all filters together
   @param string filterType (the property that will be filtered upon)
   @param string value (selected filter value)
   @return undefined
  */
  function filterCtrl(filterType, value) {
    // result array
    var results = [];

    if (isInt(value)) {
      filter[filterType] = parseInt(value);
    } else {
      filter[filterType] = value;
    }

    for (k in filter) {
      if (!filter.hasOwnProperty(k) && !(filter[k] !== 0)) {
        // all the filters are off
        loadMarkers();
        return false;
      } else if (filter[k] !== 0) {
        // call filterMap function and append to r array
        results.push(filterMap[k](filter[k]));
      } else {
        // fail silently
      }
    }

    if (filter[filterType] === 0) results.push(personData);

    /*
     if there is 1 array (1 filter applied) set it,
     else find markers that are common to every results array (pass every filter)
    */
    if (results.length === 1) {
      results = results[0];
    } else {
      results = reduceArray(results);
    }

    loadMarkers(results);

  }

  /* 
   The keys in this need to be mapped 1-to-1 with the keys in the filter variable.
  */
  filterMap = {
    /*date: function( value ) {
     return filterIntsLessThan('date_s', value);
    },
    */
    year: function(value) {
      return filterByString('date_s', value);
    },
    month: function(value) {
      return filterByString('month', value);
    },
    name: function(value) {
      return filterByString('firstname', value);
    },
    farm: function(value) {
      return filterByString('farm', value);
    },
    type: function(value) {
      return filterByString('type', value);
    }
  }

  /*
   Filters marker data based upon a string match
   @param string dataProperty (the key that will be filtered upon)
   @param string value (selected filter value)
   @return array (people that made it through the filter)
  */
  function filterByString(dataProperty, value) {
    var people = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < personData.length; i++) {
      var person = personData[i];
      if (person[dataProperty] == value) {
        people.push(person);
      } else {
        removePersonMarker(person.id);
      }
    }
    return people;
  }

  /*
   Filters out integers that are under the provided value
   @param string dataProperty (the key that will be filtered upon)
   @param int value (selected filter value)
   @return array (people that made it through the filter)
  */
  function filterIntsLessThan(dataProperty, value) {
    var people = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < personData.length; i++) {
      var person = personData[i];
      if (person[dataProperty] > value) {
        people.push(person)
      } else {
        removePersonMarker(person.id);
      }
    }
    return people;
  }

  // Takes all the filters off
  function resetFilter() {
    filter = {
      //followers: 0,
      //college: 0,
      //from: 0, 
      type: 0,
      firstname: 0,
      date_s: 0,
      month: 0,
      date: 0,
      farm: 0
    }
  }

  return {
    init: init,
    loadMarkers: loadMarkers,
    filterCtrl: filterCtrl,
    resetFilter: resetFilter
  };
}();


$(function() {

  var mapConfig = {
    idSelector: 'map-canvas',
    // now set with custom markers 
    //markerLocation: 'img/red-fat-marker.png'
    // map.fitBounds(bounds);
    // map.panToBounds(bounds);
  }

  myMap.init(mapConfig);

  $('.load-btn').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // reset everything
    $('select').val(0);
    myMap.resetFilter();
    myMap.loadMarkers();


    if ($this.hasClass('is-success')) {
      $this.removeClass('is-success').addClass('is-default');
    }
  });


  $('.name-select').on('change', function() {
    myMap.filterCtrl('name', this.value);
  });

  $('.farm-select').on('change', function() {
    myMap.filterCtrl('farm', this.value);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    myMap.panTo(bounds);
  });

  $('.type-select').on('change', function() {
    myMap.filterCtrl('type', this.value);
  });

  $('.year-select').on('change', function() {
    myMap.filterCtrl('year', this.value);
  });
  $('.month-select').on('change', function() {
    myMap.filterCtrl('month', this.value);
  });

});
var personData = [{
    "id": "18",
    "firstname": "Jim",
    "type": "Grape",
    "farm": "Sweet",
    "lat": "44.231953",
    "lng": "-116.908485",
    "date_s": "2016",
    "month": "12"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "firstname": "Grant",
    "type": "Grape",
    "farm": "Kerner",
    "lat": "44.232029",
    "lng": "-116.891426",
    "date_s": "2016",
    "month": "11"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "firstname": "Grant",
    "type": "Apple",
    "farm": "Kerner",
    "lat": "44.252029",
    "lng": "-116.811426",
    "date_s": "2017",
    "month": "11"
  },
  {
    "id": "29",
    "firstname": "Grant",
    "type": "Corn",
    "farm": "Two Rivers",
    "lat": "44.229061",
    "lng": "-116.970703",
    "date_s": "2018",
    "month": "11"
  }
]
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 210px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="st-container" class="st-container">
  <?php
   // don't add header  until above is removed
   include '/www/rivers/hunt/includes/header.php';
  //include '/www/rivers/hunt/includes/menu.php';
  ?>
    <div class="outer-container">

      <div class="inner-container cf">
        <div class="map-container">
          <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="filter-container-lg">
          <div>
            <p>Filter</p>
            <div class="filter-options">
              <div class="filter-set" style="margin-top:0;">
                <button id="load-btn" class="load-btn button is-success">Reload data</button>
              </div>

              <div class="filter-set">
                <label for="name-select">Name:</label>
                <select name="name-select" id="name-select" class="name-select">
                  <option value="0">Any</option>
                  <option value="Grant">Grant</option>
                  <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
                  <option value="Other" disabled>Other</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="filter-set">
                <label for="type-select">Type:</label>
                <select name="type-select" id="type-select" class="type-select">
                  <option value="0">Any</option>
                  <option value="Grape">Grape</option>
                  <option value="Quail">Quail</option>
                  <option value="Corn">Corn</option>
                  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                  <option value="Hen">Hen</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="filter-set">
                <label for="year-select">Year:</label>
                <select name="year-select" id="year-select" class="year-select">
                  <option value="0">Any</option>
                  <option value="2016">2016</option>
                  <option value="2017">2017</option>
                  <option value="2018">2018</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="filter-set">
                <label for="month-select">Month:</label>
                <select name="month-select" id="month-select" class="month-select">
                  <option value="0">Any</option>
                  <option value="10">Oct</option>
                  <option value="11">Nov</option>
                  <option value="12">Dec</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="filter-set">
                <label for="farm-select">Farm:</label>
                <select name="farm-select" id="farm-select" class="farm-select">
                  <option value="0">Any</option>
                  <option value="Sweet">Sweet</option>
                  <option value="Two Rivers">Two Rivers</option>
                  <option value="Kerner">Kerner</option>
                </select>
              </div>



            </div>
            <!-- .filter-options -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .filter-container-lg -->

        <div id="status"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- .inner-container -->
    </div>
    <!-- .outer-container -->

</div>
<!-- #st-container -->
```